# To provide nicer logging when a Spring property is invalid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

Using a application.properties file my Spring Boot app can use some property values in it. A way to make sure a mandatory value must present is to add an annotation `@Value` for the property. The problem with this is the app fails miserably if the property value is not there in the properties file.

I am after a nicer less horrible way to say printing out a log line about "Property A is missing" instead of a whole stack trace. Is there a way to do this while still using `@Value` to initialise the properties? For example, property A is mandatory, an error is logged before app exits; property B is missing but not mandatory, a warning is logged and app continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can identify all property, then you can write a method in Application class with @Postconstruct, and inside your method, you can manually validate and log them

```
@Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @PostConstruct
    private void validateProperties() {

        environment.getProperty(key);
        .....
        ......
    }
```

---

Alternatively, you can write your custom **EnvironmentPostProcessor**, and iterate all properties and log whichever is null/empty.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not reading from the environment, I am reading from application.properties file.

Comment: Spring automatically populates **application.properties** in environment

Answer (score 0):

As you're using spring-boot consider creating a `@ConfigurationProperties` class rather than using the `@Value` annotation.

By doing that you can do your validations using [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/), also in the same class, you can implement the interface `InitializingBean` and add extra validations/log messages as you with.

[Follow this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-java-bean-binding) on Spring's official docs to read more about `@ConfigurationProperties`.